# Subtract two records of the same column in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am using PostgreSQL and I want to subtract two records of the same table and use the result in the same query.

Here is the table:

#### Scores

6
8
9

---

#### Result

6
   2
   1

What I want to do:

```
Result = Score(i) - Score(i-1)
```

In the end I want the sum of these results. `sum(result)` must be 9 in my example.

Answer (score 5):

You need some way to determine the sequence of rows in `score`. There is no "natural order" in a table in a relational database. So I assume you have an `id` (or a timestamp or something) to order your records by. Or is `i` guaranteed to be greater in every new row? Then you can just order by `i`.

The query itself is simple - once you find out about [**window functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT i - lag(i, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS result
FROM   score
ORDER  BY id;
```

Including an improvement by @Clodoaldo (see comment).

```
lag(i, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id)
```

is equivalent to, but more elegant than:

```
COALESCE(lag(i) OVER (ORDER BY id), 0)
```

Purpose is to cover the special case of the first row that has no preceding row.
[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b6dd3/3)

`sum(result)` is trivial because it is bound to equal the last `i` according to your description:

```
SELECT i
FROM   score
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: +1 But wouldn't it be preferably to use `lag(i, 1, 0)` in instead of the `coalesce`?

Comment: @Clodoaldo: I agree, that's simpler. Updated the answer with your idea.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter well thanks for the explanation but what I meant with the sum is the sum of the column result so here it is 6 + 2 + 1 that what gave 9 but it is coincidence the same as last value of the score

Thanks

Comment: @Lily: It is not coincidence but a logic consequence - according to your description. Please provide another example if you have different results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(rx.diff,rx.val))
  FROM
(SELECT x.val,
        x.val - lag(x.val) over () as diff
  FROM (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[6,8,9]) as val) AS x) AS rx
```

Substituting your table select for my unnest which just generates the data as per your example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but if I want a table that I do not know it is entries or it has unlimited entries, that means I can not put the array in this form what should I do?
or is it impossible to do that ?

Comment: @Lily: The array in Gavin's example is obviously just to provide example values and not meant to be part of your solution. The one thing missing, though, is an `ORDER BY` clause. Without it, the result of `lag()` is (implementation specific) arbitrary. Also, `COALESCE` is in the wrong place.