# Unordered result using order by query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgis

I'm using `pgr_astar` function of PostgreSQL to get the optimal path, and I mentioned that the result should be ordered by `seq`:

```
cur.execute("create table %s as SELECT a.seq, a.id1 AS node, a.id2 AS edge, 
b.source, b.target, b.cost, b.reverse_cost, b.km, b.%s, b.%s, b.estimated_time as time, b.ang_elev, b.geom_way
FROM pgr_astar ('SELECT id, source, target, cost as cost, x1, y1, x2, y2, reverse_cost FROM chicago_2po_4pgr', %s, %s, true, true) as a
LEFT JOIN chicago_2po_4pgr as b  ON a.id2 = b.id order by seq    
 " %(nom_table,colonne_cost,colonne_cost_reverse,depart,destination))
```

And I'm getting this result (sequences are not ordered)

```
0
.
.
124
125
135
136
137
138
139
140
129
130
131
132
133
134
```

Any suggestion please? How can I modify this query to get an ordered result.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, yes I'm looking at the right table, and usally it sorts sequences correctly. I didn't find any expalnation of this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you *query* rows from the table created with your displayed statement?

While the `ORDER BY` in the displayed query should do its job properly, that's just sorting physical rows in the newly created table. But the physical order of rows is subject to change. `VACUUM` and other background processes can reorder rows freely. Any write access to the table will do so, too.

Plus, more importantly, `SELECT * FROM tbl` is **not bound to return rows in current physical order**. While returning rows in physical order is typically the fastest way, and Postgres will typically just do that, nothing of the sort is *guaranteed*. You have to append another `ORDER BY` to get sorted rows (which defies the purpose of testing the current physical sort order).

Test the **current physical order of rows** like this:

```
SELECT ctid, * FROM tbl ORDER BY ctid;
```

Explanation for `ctid`:

- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers/66007#66007)

And verify the original `SELECT` in the question by running it without `CREATE TABLE AS`, and you'll see perfectly sorted rows ...

Related:

- [Subtract two records of the same column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153980/subtract-two-records-of-the-same-column-in-a-table/11156782#11156782)
- [Select last n rows without use of order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950641/select-last-n-rows-without-use-of-order-by-clause/7966628#7966628)